# Переключение между методами OnClick и OnTouch

Tags: java

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки включался метод OnToch , а если еще раз на нее нажать то включался бы метод OnClick?

Comment: никак. Это системные вызовы и вы на их "включение" влиять не можете. Если только полностью свой виджет написать, там можете "включать" что угодно и когда угодно. Зачем вам это надо? Возможно, есть более разумное решение.

Answer (score 1):

*Согласно комменту @pavlofff и во имя повышения метрик:*

Никак. Это системные вызовы и вы на их "включение" влиять не можете. Если только полностью свой виджет написать, там можете "включать" что угодно и когда угодно. Зачем вам это надо? Возможно, есть более разумное решение.

Comment: Во имя повышения метрик, проголосовал! Слава метрикам!

Comment: Отвеченным вопросам слава!